# how to call a MessageBox from a Substring?

Tags: c#, .net

How to display a messageBox when I click "Details"? like screenshot.

Please help me a solution.

```
 try
        {
            _serviceInspector = new ServiceInspector(new Uri(serviceLocation));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = false;

            lblMessage.Text = string.Format("An error (Details) occurred while attempting to find services at '{0}'.", serviceLocation);
            return;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Create a form that looks like the message box you want to display.

Comment: Ok it's just a label followed by linkbutton followed by label. After this I hope you know how to work with linkbutton.

Comment: Maybe you can make custom win form to do with it. I don't think MessageBox has feature like that.

Comment: Message Box does not contain a scrollable text area. Make a custom Winform and trigger it with whatever you choose.

Comment: sorry, that is not MessageBox, I have not really looked at it